# Spring 4: method with @Bean is intercepted recursively

Tags: java, spring, jndi, spring-aop

I have a Spring 4.3.25.RELEASE based project, where I mostly use Java based configuration and a little bit of XML configuration. The app is run on Java 7 based WebSphere server.

The Java-config is spread across multiple dependencies and subsequent modules `@Import` those classes.

In one of these `@Configuration` classes there is a strange phenomenon not occurring in others:

```java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringBaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "configuration")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Configuration.class)
    public Configuration configurationBean(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        ConfigurationBean configurationBean = new ConfigurationBean();
        configurationBean.setApplicationName(properties.getApplicationName());
        configurationBean.setBuildId(properties.getBuildId());
        configurationBean.setUmdbProgramId(properties.getUmdbProgramId());
        configurationBean.setUmdbSystemId(properties.getUmdbSystemId());
        configurationBean.setVersion(properties.getVersion());
        configurationBean.setEnv((String) env(properties).getObject());
        configurationBean.setServerEnv((String) serverEnv(properties).getObject());
        configurationBean.setTrustedOrigin((String) trustedOrigin(properties).getObject());

        return configurationBean;
    }

    @Bean("env")
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean env(ApplicationProperties properties) {
        return getJndiBean(properties.getEnvName());
    }

    // ...

    public static JndiObjectFactoryBean getJndiBean(String jndiName) {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean factoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJndiName(jndiName);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

The method `configurationBean` is invoked by the container, as it should be. This method, as you can see, invokes the methods `env`, `serverEnv`, `trustedOrigin`. What I'd expect is for these methods to return their respective beans.

Instead, I run into a nasty StackOverflowException, which, after a lot of searching, seems to happen in the `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer`.

When the `env` method is invoked, the `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.BeanMethodInterceptor#intercept` intercepts the method invocation.

This method invokes the `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.BeanMethodInterceptor#obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory` method, which temporarily sets the `currentlyInCreation` flag of the `env` bean to false. This is a problem, because before the method would reset the flag to true, it asks the factory to instantiate the `env` bean.

This factory proceeds to invoke the `env` method, which gets intercepted again by the same `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.BeanMethodInterceptor#intercept` method.

But this time, the `factoryContainsBean(beanFactory, BeanFactory.FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX + beanName) &&
                    factoryContainsBean(beanFactory, beanName)` expression becomes true because the `currentlyInCreation` flag has been set to false, which in turn results in the `intercept` method to ask the beanFactory to instantiate the been, restarting the infinite interception loop, until a `StackOverflowError` occurs.

Anyone faced this problem before? How can this be resolved?

PS.: Here is part of the stack trace that I managed to dig out, I do believe this is the most relevant part:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isSingleton(AbstractBeanFactory.java:433)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.obtainBeanInstanceFromFactory(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at com.generali.spring.SpringBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2ee81e.env(<generated>)
    at com.generali.spring.SpringBaseConfiguration.configurationBean(SpringBaseConfiguration.java:25)
    at com.generali.spring.SpringBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2ee81e.CGLIB$configurationBean$0(<generated>)
    at com.generali.spring.SpringBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2ee81e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1b2e723f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.generali.spring.SpringBaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2ee81e.configurationBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:928)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
// Below is the repeating part
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:928)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
```

Comment: Looking at the class you are trying to outsmart Spring Boot here (judging from the `@EnableConfigurationProperties`. The `@ComponentScan` isn't needed, nor is the `@PropertySource` (Spring Boot does that for you already). Nonetheless what are the other methods doing? You included only the `env` method.

Comment: the other methods are not included, because they are essentially the same as `env`. Only that they call other getters of `ApplicationProperties`

Comment: the `@ComponentScan` is needed, because I have other beans and configuration classes in that package. Maybe the `@PropertySource` can be left out, I'll try without

Comment: I would suggest to use a different name then`configuration` (could be an internally used bean), also `env` is also used as an internal bean name, rename that as well.. If this bean is used very early in the process full config parsing might not have happend, leading to some interesting results.

Comment: okay, I'll try. These names come from a legacy configuration that has been refactored to newer version of spring/boot

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace? Also it should work without `@ComponentScan` assuming that Spring Boot detects this class already, it will detect the others as well! It wasn't just a legacy config migration it was also a migratin to Spring Boot apparently. Feels like another case of doing multiple things in one go (move to Spring Boot and change config from XML to Java).

Comment: Spring finds this class because it is explicitly imported with the `@Import` annotation on another `@Configuration` class

Comment: tried changing the bean names without luck

Comment: Please include the other methods, as well as (part of) the stacktrace.

Comment: okay, the stacktrace one is tricky, because the logger needs to go through so many causes that a stackoverflow happens there as well, but I'll do my best

Comment: I included the stack trace

Comment: Try to remove the `ApplicationProperties` from the method signatures and `@Autowire` it into the configuraiton class. This will delay the construction a little, which will influence the lifecycle.

Comment: László, instead of keeping M. Deinum guess, trying to help you without seeing a complete picture, you might want to consider providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub. This way everyone willing to help could clone a small project reproducing your problem and try to help you spot problems, suggest solutions etc. Wouldn't that be nice and just what you actually want? Please enable your helpers to help you. Thanks.

Comment: That would be nice indeed, however I'm in a complete gray area, where I don't know how can the problem be reproduced. Unfortunately, I can't share the whole project, due to company policy, however I have some update, which will be edited into the original question shortly (or in an answer, if I find it to work correctly)

Comment: I successfully localized the problem. I'm searching for a solution right now, but when asking this question, I was way off about where the problem is and what causes it. I think i would be better of opening a new question, because this comment section and edit history is filled with searching in the wrong direction. I will link here the question, if anyone of you is interested. For now, thank you for your time, especially M. Deinum